# How to remove elements from an array using DDP

Tags: meteor, ddp

I am about to build a feature in our DDP server (https://github.com/cortexlang/web) that allows a user to subscribe for a window of historic values for a given document. A simple subscription for historical values could look like:

```
connection.subscribe("MyCollection", {history:{from_last:0, to_last:10}})
```

This will return the last 10 samples for each document in the `MyCollection` collection in an array. For example, suppose `MyCollection` contains one document with a single numeric value, the result of the above subscription could be:

```
[0, 2, 5, 3, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5, 5]
```

These windows could potentially be quite large. Therefore, sending over the entire array when a new value is added would be wasteful. Instead, it would be nice if I could only push in new values to the client, and push out old values.

For example, suppose my document is updated with a new value '3'. My array should now look like:

```
[3, 0, 2, 5, 3, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5]
```

Here, I could have sent the entire array again. It would however be much more efficient if I could only send the '3', and remove the '5'.

I noticed that DDP has a `cleared` field in the `changed` message which allows DDP to clear fields in a document, but I can't figure out yet from the documentation (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md) how to remove elements from an array.